# can't understand warnings in simple Pl/SQL function

Tags: plsql

I am using Oracle 10g with SqlDeveloper. When I execute the following code, it says

"FUNCTION wafadar compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning"

```
create or replace function wafadar
return varchar2(10)
is

cursor c1 is
SELECT employee_id,first_name FROM employees where department_id=50 ;

begin
  for i in c1
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.first_name);
  end loop;
  return 'hello';
end;
```

SHOW ERRORS at the end is also not showing the warnings. Why are the warnings there ?

Comment: Can you try running it through SQLPlus? Do you get the same result ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it and can't download it either (office environment)

Comment: From the manual:"SQL*Plus is an interactive and batch query tool that is installed with every Oracle Database installation. It has a command-line user interface."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Errors!**

At first, you should care about errors, and I bet you have one on the return clause of your function (you **can't specify the size** of the "**varchar2**".

**Warnings**

Did you look for "warning" in the manuals?
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#LNPLS00711

**How to see warnings**(enable categories you need)

```
alter function wafadar compile plsql_warnings='ENABLE:ALL' reuse settings
```

**Check**:

```
select plsql_warnings
from   user_plsql_object_settings ps
where  ps.name = 'WAFADAR'
```

**Your warnings:**

Client tools like sql*plus or Sql Developer(if supported):

```
 show errors
```

or

```
select *
from   user_errors ur
where  ur.name = 'WAFADAR'

NAME                           TYPE           SEQUENCE       LINE   POSITION TEXT                                                                             ATTRIBUTE MESSAGE_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- --------------
WAFADAR                        FUNCTION              1          1          1 PLW-05018: unit WAFADAR omitted optional AUTHID clause; default value DEFINER us WARNING             5018
```

---

**Finally**, I suggest you to read a little bit of:

1. How to ask: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before
2. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/toc.htm
3. All the "**oracles**" are here: http://tahiti.oracle.com/
4. Sql developer **oracles**(if you want to use it!): http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/toc.htm