# PL/SQL execution completed with warning?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I typed the following code in separate pages, it said invalid procedure name. When typed together in the same work-space in SQL Developer it says execution completed with warning. There seems to be no output at all.

It's a college exercise,to get several values from several tables using one value entered by the user - in this case `ono`.

Here we should get the title of book, quantity ordered and customername using order number (`ono`).

This is my code:

```
create or replace procedure proc2 ( ono in number
                    , cname out varchar, book out varchar, qty out number) is
   temp number;
begin    
   select custid into temp from ordr where orderno = ono;
   select custname into cname from customer where custid = temp;
   select isbn,qtystock into temp,qty from order_list where orderno = ono;
   select title into book from books where isbn = temp;
end proc2;
```

and my main calling function:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
   cname varchar(7);
   book varchar(7);
   ono number;
   qty number;
begin
   ono := &ono; -- I even tried explicitly giving a value didn't work
   proc2(ono, cname, book, qty);
   dbms_output.put_line('customer name: '||cname||'book title :'||book||'quantity ordered   :'||qty);
end;
```

The procedure has executed successfully, but I can't seem to find the mistake in the main function. What do you think is wrong?

Even when I executed the following I get function executed successfully and when i execute main function i get executed with warning,i don't understand why!

function:

```
create or replace function totfun(ip in number) return number is
t number(5);
t1 number(5);
t2 number(5);
begin
select isbn,qtystock into t,t1 from order_list where orderno=ip;
select price into t2 from books where isbn=t;
return t1*t2;
end totfun;
```

main function:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
ip number;
begin
ip:=&orderno;
dbms_output.put_line(totfun(ip));
end;
```

Comment: Use `show errors` to see the compilation errors after the `CREATE...`. You should also get read of the multiple `SELECT` statements. As far as I can tell, you can get the same information with just a single statement `JOIN`ing the tables.

Comment: that's a nice idea i'll try it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> Before exiting a subprogram, assign values to all OUT formal
>   parameters.  Otherwise,the corresponding actual parameters will be
>   null. If you exit successfully, PL/SQL  assigns values to the actual
>   parameters. If you exit with an unhandled exception,  PL/SQL does not
>   assign values to the actual parameters.

Do you have assigned values to your output parameters?

**What are your output parameters before to exit from proc2?**

Could it be useful to trace your code inside the procedure proc2?

What are your warnings?

[***Warnings: useful to read(link)***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439037/cant-understand-warnings-in-simple-pl-sql-function/6440544#6440544)